# What containers/classes do I want to use for the following android game?

Tags: android, canvas, imagebutton

I am programming an android game that has a screen, which has a ScrollView that contains almost everything on the screen.  I need to have image elements that **move** around, can be **clicked** on (but also be transparent to clicks in certain situations)  that have **multiple layers** and **animations**.

Should I use layered Imagebuttons? there can potentially be doezens of them on the screen at once, and i don't know if there are memory concerns about having 200 imagebuttons on a screen.

Do I need to use a canvas? I have seen canvases in many examples, but i don't know if they are the best option.

Is there some other class or way of doing this that is better?

any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be best served by an [Android game library](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/89/are-there-any-2d-gaming-libraries-frameworks-engines-for-android). Check also [e3roid](http://www.e3roid.com/).